# React Native: best practice to setInterval and Promises with setState in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, setinterval

I'm currently battling this "cannot setState() or forceUpdate() on unmounted component error" and having a hard time tracing which async operation the error is from. I'm suspecting it's because of the `setInterval` I use to add seconds to display current time. Here's what I have in `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount` that are responsible for managing the time display:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;

    //listener to identify whether app is active/inactive
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this));

    //get user's intranet schedule
    this.props.actionsMain.getSchedule(this.props.staff.staffID);

    this.getLocation();
    //After the first location received, re-check every 20 seconds
    this.locationInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getLocation();
    }, 20000);
  }

componentDidUpdate() {
    //when we just received server time, parse and set the time to state, then set the interval timer
    if (this.props.scheduleReceived && this.state.time[0] === null) {
      let time = this.props.schedule['time_server'].split(':'),
        hh = parseInt(time[0]) + this.props.location.zone,
        mm = parseInt(time[1]),
        ss = parseInt(time[2]);

      if (this.mounted) {
        this.setState({ time: [hh, mm, ss] });

        this.serverTimeInterval = setInterval(() => {
          let { time } = this.state, hh = time[0], mm = time[1], ss = time[2];

          //add second and adjust time
          ss += 1;
          if (ss >= 60) {
            ss -= 60;
            mm += 1;

            if (mm >= 60) {
              mm -= 60;
              hh += 1;

              if (hh >= 24)
                hh -= 24;
            }
          }

          if (this.mounted)
            this.setState({ time: [hh, mm, ss] })
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    //Remove all timer events
    clearInterval(this.serverTimeInterval);
    clearInterval(this.locationInterval);

    //Remove listener
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this));

    this.mounted = false;
  }
```

Can anyone point out what I have done wrong here and if even what I'm doing is a good practice at all?

Also on the same note, my second suspicion would comes from fetch location promise that was executed from the `setInterval()` and returned to an unmounted component. If there's any rule of thumb that I can follow on how I can make sure that setInterval, setState and Promises work harmoniously that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should never call setState in componentDidUpdate, it will result in infinite loop

Comment: I know about that, that's not causing infinite loop due to the conditions I put in, the problem is definitely not that, though it may not be a good practice. So where would you suggest I put the execution of the stuff I put in `componentDidUpdate` currently? I need them to run after `componentDidMount` and that's the only place I could think of to put them right now..